# Setting preferred size to a JFrame or its Content Pane

Tags: java, swing

I am currently trying to understand the differences between

`frame.getContentPane().setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600, 400));`

and

`frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600, 400));`

It is highly appreciated if anyone could help me out.

```
public class AutoCredit extends JFrame {

    JFrame frame = new JFrame();

    public AutoCredit() {
        frame.getContentPane().setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600, 400));
        frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600, 400));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        AutoCredit tp = new AutoCredit();
        tp.setSize(900, 400);
        tp.setVisible(true);

    }

}
```

Comment: Setting the preferred size of the content pane is more 'reliable' when the GUI needs that much space (e.g. for a game surface) since it accounts for the frame decorations (which will make the size of the complete GUI larger). Unless of course the frame is undecorated, but by that stage, it makes more sense to use a `JWindow` instead. Having said that, neither should be done. **Instead** either override the preferred size method in a component added to the content pane for a custom painted GUI, or otherwise leave it to the default sizes of the components (with borders, padding etc.).

Comment: Hi Andrew, thank you for your answers. I keep on seeing the word "Content Pane" but I don't actually see it or know where is it. Is there a way to make the "Content Pane" visible so that I can see that it is actually there? e.g to see content pane in one color and JFrame in another.

Comment: *"Is there a way to make the "Content Pane" visible so that I can see that it is actually there?"* `frame.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.PINK);`. It might also be helpful to `System.out.println(frame.getContentPane());` ..

Comment: I tried frame.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.PINK); and it doesn't work.

Comment: Try it without adding anything to the content pane.

Comment: It worked when I do it this way without putting "frame" in front.

getContentPane().setBackground(Color.PINK);

Thanks..

Comment: That is because you  initialize tow `JFrame` instances. You calss extends `JFrame` (which means **it is** a `JFrame`) and yet you initialize another `JFrame` instance by `JFrame frame = new JFrame()`. Also when you add an opaque component you don't see the content pane. To get better idea of the root pane layers see [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/rootpane.html)